# Displaying German language characters in text view

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I have a string which contain some **German language characters** and Im setting in **Textview** but some characters are not showing but a box instead of them . here is code:

```
   @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_german);
        TextView abc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.abc);
        String chararc = getString(R.string.german);

        try {
            final String s = new String(chararc.getBytes(), "UTF-8");
            abc.setText(s);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_german, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

here is string :

```
 <string name="german">Ë ø  ë Ḧ ḧ Ï ï Ḯ ḯ M̈    m̈ N̈   n̈ Ö    ö Ȫ ȫ Ṏ ṏ P̈    p̈ S̈   s̈ T̈   ẗÜ  ü Ǖ ǖ Ǘ ǘ Ǚ ǚ Ǜ ǜ Ṳ ṳ Ṻ ṻ V̈    v̈ Ẅ    ẅ Ẍ ẍ Ÿ ÿ
</string>
```

Comment: If you are using eclipse try this : `Right ckick on xml file` -> `Preferences` -> `XML` -> `XML Files` -> Change encoding to `UTF-8` -> OK.

Comment: Android works fine with non-english characters. The problem is in your text file, try to open it in Notepad++ and verify that its encoding is utf-8.

Comment: Here is described the same problem that you have.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8383889/german-characters-display-in-textview

Answer (score 0):

You should try using [Html.fromHtml](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html)

```
...
abc.setText(Html.fromHtml(s));
...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you created your project using the Android SDK Tools (read Creating an Android Project), the tools create a `res/` directory in the top level of the project. Within this `res/`directory are subdirectories for various resource types. There are also a few default files such as `res/values/strings.xml`, which holds your string values.

Once you’ve decided on the languages you will support, create the resource subdirectories and string resource files. For example:

```
MyProject/
   res/
   values/
       strings.xml
   values-es/
       strings.xml
   values-fr/
       strings.xml
   values-de/
       strings.xml
```

[Ref](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html),[Ref2](http://developer.vodafone.com/how-support-multiple-languages-android/)